# How to save an Instagram user Picture to my local machine using C#

Tags: c#, instagram-api

I would like to develop a desktop application using WPF(CSharp). While researching how to do this I can see a post where developers are a complaint about API accessing the API. Most complaints were web based do this effect what I am trying to achieve.

Ideally, I would like to be able-able to find any user profile, Image search/Hashtag and be able to save the image locally.

with twitter I was able to search user and their tweets and save them locally using link to twitter is there a similar library for Instagram?

What steps do I need to take to achieve this(or sample applications/tutorial)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think anyone is going to give you exact steps on how to achieve that, but I can point you into this direction : https://www.instagram.com/developer/. You will need to register your app in order to get the necessary tokens and access public content. Concerning WPF, there are plenty tutorials that can help you.

I also found [this article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/raj1979/how-to-authenticate-and-get-data-using-instagram-api/) about authenticating and fetching data from Instagram API, you might find it interesting.

Unfortunately, I don't think you are going to get a more precise answer, since your question is quite broad.

Comment: what I would like to know is it possible to get public_content without getting permission from Instagram because I have been reading but I still don't understand why everyone is complaining. All the tutorials and resources I have found was written before the Instagram new term and conditions this is why am asking butI will follow the article you sent me later today cheers.

Comment: most of the projects that I came across were done before june 2016. The tools that I have found are out dated